# Power BI synced drill-down

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, drilldown

I am currently developing a live report for colleagues to use to investigate a certain business area.

I've tried to find a solution to be able to sync the drill down function on all charts on the report to always show the same data.

My charts all use the same x-axis (datetime), but currently, to my understanding, I have to drill down individually on each chart to align them.

Does anyone know a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. You can try using bookmarks, which works until you try to use slicer at the same time.